# filtering from sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I use my SQL for my app. 
Say I have a table of all registered users for my app.
say I have users at hand and I want to filter (or select) from my database the only ones that are registered. 
For example my data base have user1,user2......user100
and input user set : user3,user5,user10,user999,user2000 so the output of the query will be : user3,user5 and user 10 only.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Share code, not a description.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Before asking question, learn how to ask question!!!  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want `in`:

```
select t.*
from t
where user_id in ('user3', 'user5', 'user10', 'user999', 'user2000')
```

This will return only the matching users.

Answer (score 1):

The format the user is passing these values is very important  here. I am assuming that you have different rows of information. If in that case, you could make use of the below code.

```
Declare @MyTableVar table
 (User_ID VARCHAR(32) primary key)

INSERT  @MyTableVar VALUES ('user3')
INSERT  @MyTableVar VALUES ('user5')
INSERT  @MyTableVar VALUES ('user10')
INSERT  @MyTableVar VALUES ('user999')
INSERT  @MyTableVar VALUES ('user2000')

SELECT * 
  FROM @MyTableVar 
  WHERE User_ID NOT IN (SELECT USER_ID FROM database.schema.table_name)
```

If your user is passing values in the same row you can convert them to multiple rows using CROSS APPLY. Example can be seen [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1149629/Converting-a-single-row-into-Multiple-rows)

Kartheek